# img with dd tag causes table width to exceed allotted width

Tags: html, css

In my html page I have this in a table td tag:

```
<dd>
  <img src="images/Step_response_3_pole.jpg" title="Step response" style="width: 830px; height: 500px; cursor: move;">
</dd>
```

So this shifts it right by a certain amount. Ideally I would like to have the image start from the left most margin in the table cell so that I cam make the image the largest possible. 
I have set the image max-width to the maximum width of the image without the dd tag. Now on some pages which get generated with the dd tag causes the table to expand more than the width of the table I want.

So the only solution I can think of is to make the image max-width even smaller to accommodate the shift with the dd tag but then it wastes image area for even those images which do not have the dd tag.

Is there a way I can get around this or somehow disable the dd tag for images?

All I want is my table to respect the maximum width I have allotted for it.

Comment: What is the <dd> tag doing there?

Comment: It is generated because it is a list so it is nested in a dl and li tags.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried that I get a 40px margin put in on dd elements by my browser (i.e. a user-agent style). I can remove that like this by using the following style to reset the browser defaults:

```
dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Have you tried something like that?

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little but I see that the dd was nested in a dl tag so even when the dd offset was 0 the dl still has an offset. Anything that can be done for that? I tried the same for dl i.e. margin:0; but that did not do anything. Also it would be really great if anything that we change works only in the case of images.

Comment: Ya, so adjust the margin & padding on the dl as well, and then you can also target the image tags inside the dd: `dd img { ...}`.

Comment: Hi user1246028, it's a bit hard to tell exactly what needs to be done without seeing a bit more of the HTML you are styling. As Revent says though, you should be able to reset the styles added to the other elements too. Happy to have a look if you post up the structure.

Comment: Here is the web page that shows the problem:  http://www.amved.com/milindsweb/Opamps.html    so as you can see the table in which the content is is wider that is due to the first 3 images that reside in the li dl dd structure.

Comment: I added this `dd img{
  margin: 0;
}
dl img{
 margin: 0;
}
li img{
 margin: 0;
}` but this does not do anything

Comment: Wow! You have my sympathies! So after making my change with the dd margin (setting to 0) the image is actually flush up against edge of the table. It's just that a lot of the image is white. You can add this to the style attribute of the image to tweak it over though: margin-left: -40px;

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. When I just add `dd {margin: 0;}` then the image does move left but does not go to the edge of the table. It goes to the left and is now in line with the list text. The list text has an offset from the edge of the table which is caused by the list item numbers. I have this in the screenshot here temporarily - [Screenshot with dd margin set to 0](http://www.amved.com/milindsweb/img_dd0.png). Are you able to shift the image right up to the table edge?

Comment: If I add margin-left: -40px; to the img style then it works for this image but then other images on other pages which are not inside lists like this page are shifted out of the table!

Comment: You can add this to the styles: dl dd img {margin-left: -40px;} to just apply it to images that are inside dd and dl tags.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it. I added `li dl dd img { margin: -80px}`